Making A Roblox Time Trial Obby and can't seem to make a timer in my format
I'm making a roblox time trials obby, but I can't make a timer in the format of 0:00s, any help ?
i tried multiple times, but nothing worked I used a very basic script but the format looks quite ugly. Please help, I've been trying for months on end to figure it out.

We'd love to help, care to share the code that you tried?

ngl, I deleted all the code, so I don't have it. but kylaaa, thank you! you were the one who wrote the script for the last timer! this time, can you walk me step by step, I'm a beginner learner, thanks! (also in the format of 0.00s if possible! thanks

I could talk you through it, but I don't want to simply write your code for you. The point of this website is for you to try something first, and then figure out specifically what isn't working and then ask for help how to fix it. If you need a starting point, take a look at the docs for string formatting, and some ways to get the time that has passed.

You can use a function like the one below to get a string in the format 0:00s.
--!strict

function formatTime(seconds: number): string
    local minutes = math.floor(seconds / 60)
    local remainingSeconds = seconds % 60

    return string.format("%d:%02ds", minutes, remainingSeconds)
end

print(formatTime(300)) -- 5:00s

The function takes a number which is the amount of seconds and then returns a string in the format 0:00s.
First, we use math.floor to find the number of minutes. Then, we use % to divide the number of seconds by 60 and get the reminder of seconds after dividing them. Finally, we use string.format to put the minutes and remaining seconds together in a string, making sure that remainingSeconds has 2 digits.

nw, i already fixed it
